# Getting CSS border value with jQuery in Firefox 14.0.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I run the following code in the Firebug console.

```
$('img').css('border', 'solid 2px red').css('border');
```

The red image borders appear, but it returns an empty string, why is this?

It works fine in Chrome and Safari developer tools.

**Update**: The jQuery docs say that shorthand properties are not supported when getting CSS values. However I have also tried the following with no luck in Firefox (All work in Chrome and Safari)

```
$('img').css('border-style', 'solid').css('border-style');
$('img').css('borderStyle', 'solid').css('borderStyle');
$('img').css('border', 'solid 2px green').css('borderStyle');
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quoting [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) docs.

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, **border**) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: `$(elem).css('marginTop')` and `$(elem).css('marginRight')`, and so on.

For the case of [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border), you need to use the `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color` related properties.

e.g. `border-color`:

```
$('img').css('border-top-color', 'red').css('borderTopColor');
$('img').css('border-right-color', 'red').css('borderRightColor');
$('img').css('border-bottom-color', 'red').css('borderBottomColor');
$('img').css('border-left-color', 'red').css('borderLeftColor');
```

Comment: I also tried `$('img').css('border-style', 'solid').css('border-style')` and `$('img').css('borderStyle', 'solid').css('borderStyle')` but this did not work on Firefox either. I also tried `$('img').css('border', 'solid 2px green').css('borderStyle')`

Comment: `borderStyle` is a shorthand also

Comment: @Mike, It works, check that property typo you have there. It is `border-top-style` not `border-style-top`

Comment: Sorry I pasted the code from Abody97, which has now been deleted. Thanks for your help! I should have read that more carefully... my fault for always developing on Chrome!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var border = $('img').css('border', '2px solid red')[0].style.border;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xZXDM/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Supported properties in firefox:

```
'border-top-color'
'border-right-color'
'border-bottom-color'
'border-left-color'

'border-top-width'
'border-right-width'
'border-bottom-width'
'border-left-width'

'border-top-style'
'border-right-style'
'border-bottom-style'
'border-left-style'
```

Are the supported longhands :) Cheers! Enjoy!!!

You can still use shorthand to set border in most cases.

If you are sure they are the same do something like

```
var borderString = $('img').css('border-top-width') + " " 
                 + $('img').css('border-top-style') + " " 
                 + $('img').css('border-top-color');
```

to get the string like "`2px solid rgb(255,255,255)'`

Comment: @EnesUnal just to make sure `'border-color'` `'border-style'` etc are not supported either, check the other comment, he tried one of that :) Sorry if that annoyed you.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure now what a personality you have. Have a **good day**

Comment: @EnesUnal Hey, just got the meaning of the comment now:) I didnt see your edit, just saw it now, was editing myself after your comment :) Sorry if that annoyed you again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to use multiple properties
use the following syntax

$('img').css({'border':'solid 2px red','color':'green'})

the shorthand property not supported in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var objImage = $('img').css('border', 'solid 2px red');
objImage.css('border-top-color');
objImage.css('border-top-width');
objImage.css('border-top-style');
```

Not just for `top`, it is also applicable for `right`, `left`, and `bottom`.

This is also a non-working code :

```
objImage.css('border-style');
```

Since `border`, `margin`, `padding` properties of CSS is seperately editable. If `border-top` is different than `border-left`, browser may be confused which it must return when you just asked `border`.