# jquery `css` function doesn't return `border-color` property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get `border-color` property and I try to do that with `css()` function

```
$('.panel-warning').css('border-color')
```

But its empty

Html

```
<div class="col-md-4 is-draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging">
    <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">Intermediate Outcome</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-warning {
    border-color: #faebcc;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqsrq4e5/1/)

Comment: Your code appears to be working. I see the `rgb` value in the `alert`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan browser?

Comment: Your fiddle works OK.

Comment: @Pointy Chrome 43 on Win8.1

Comment: If you want the hex value and not the rgb look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Comment: ok, doesn't work if FF

Comment: What does Chrome do if (for example) top and bottom are different colors?

Comment: @Pointy I get the colours listed separately in TRBL order.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan wow that's not what I'd expect, but OK.  Well that means that you need to know what's going on with code for either behavior.

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal. I prefer FF's implementation of forcing you to reference the specific border side. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eqsrq4e5/2/), and what I see in the console in Chrome: `rgb(204, 0, 0) rgb(0, 204, 0) rgb(0, 0, 204) rgb(204, 204, 0)`

Comment: Anyone an idea why `document.querySelector(".panel-warning")` returns *null* in that fiddle (FF 39, Mac OSX 10.10)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - css('border-width') returning as an empty string on Firefox but not on Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175938/jquery-cssborder-width-returning-as-an-empty-string-on-firefox-but-not-on)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to go to the individual top, left, right, and bottom properties.

Firefox won't work unless you do that:

```
$('.panel-warning').css('border-left-color')
```

This is, of course, sort-of a pain and a burden, but those really are separately settable so I don't see that there's any way to avoid having your JavaScript know what to look for.

Chrome apparently does you a favor here, though it may get weird when the different sides really do have different colors. (Good bet that it's a core WebKit behavior, meaning that Safari and Opera *probably* do that too.)

Comment: It's kind-of a pain but then since the colors really are separate properties, it's hard to know what Chrome is up to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('.panel-warning').css('border-color'));
});
```

or put your javascript code at the end of the file, after the html and css code